# How to generate Code Churn in VSTS? (Azure DevOps)

Tags: project-management, azure-devops

[In this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sql-reports/perspective-code-analyze-report-code-churn-coverage) I noticed that is it possible to generate code churn reports for TFS:

[image]

I would like to generate the similar report using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). Is that possible and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

For now you can't.
But you have [Analytics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/analytics/analytics-widgets-vsts?view=vsts) and there is a Code part that is in the roadmap.
Take a look there anyway. It has some awesome widgets so far.